# How do I make my Chatbot to ONLY answer from 6pm to 8am - IBM Watson

Tags: chatbot, ibm-watson

I've made a chatbot in IBM Watson with the graphic tools (not coding so far), but there's no option to make it have a schedule. Would you guide me using the basic plan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a top node called `input` and under `If assistant recognizes`

- Add `now().before('18:00:00')` and `now().after('8:00:00')` - *Time is in 24 hour format*
- Assistant responds --> Text --> `We are Open only between 6 PM and 8 AM everyday`
- Then assistant should --> `Skip user input`

[image]

Add another node called `welcome` and under `welcome`

- Assistant responds --> Text --> `Welcome, how can I help?`

[image]

Check the [Expression language documentation](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-methods#dialog-methods-dates-reformatDateTime) to understand more about the use of `now()`

Once done, click `Try it` to see the chatbot to respond only between the times mentioned